# How can I have a simple commandline based OS?

Tags: kernel, compile

I have an  Cortex A8 based development board, I would like to setup a simple OS, for example to connect through SSH to the board and upload/write new program(blink led etc). The board comes with a CD which is contains the Linux kernel,

```
make zImage
```

I followed this tutorial, this is for Android, but I don't want a GUI.

After the compilation what am I supposed to do, I would like to have almost the same functionality as Ubuntu server.

What I am supposed to copy to the SD card?

Comment: ARM boards often use the *U-Boot* bootloader, and the Linux kernel in uImage files rather than zImage.  You really do not need to use `ssh` if you have a secure network.  I use `telnet` since the LAN consists of just the PC and the ARM board with a switch (using static IP addresses.)

Comment: If you don't want a GUI, then you don't need a new kernel.  Simply inhibit the start of the X server during init (the exact procedure to do this depends on the startup mechanism, but usually involves *rc* scripts).  But maybe you have misstated what you want.  Do you really want a shell in a terminal on the VGA/LCD display, **OR** did you really want a **headless** configuration with the console on the serial port, /dev/tty ?  That may require a new kernel build, or at least a new kernel command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news is there's an ubuntu port for the cortex A8 (well, for some varients). However unlike x86, there's no uniform port for them -they use varients of the same processor, so there are different versions for say, a TI, Allwinner or other ARM processor. Without knowing your exact processor type its hard to recommend a distro or build you can use.

Here's the [ubuntu builds for 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/). Likewise debian has ports as do other OSes. Chances are there's a prebuilt linux distro you can use, but once again, depends on what the dev board actually is.

Comment: The type of the processor is s5pv210(Samsung)

Comment: "*there's an ubuntu port for the cortex A8 (well, for some varients).*" - You would need to use an image that was built for your specific *board* as well as the specific version/manufacturer of an ARM Cortex A8 processor.  You have now left the comfortable world of standardized PC hardware.